# How to make requests_cache work with many concurrent requests?

Tags: python, caching, concurrency, python-requests

I'm getting and caching (for performance) lots of URLs with something like:

```
import requests
import requests_cache
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

urls = ['http://www.google.com', ...]
with requests_cache.enabled():
    responses = ThreadPool(100).map(requests.get, urls)
```

However, I'm getting a lot of errors for:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Clearly too many threads are accessing the cache at the same time.

So does [`requests_cache`](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) support some kind of transaction so that the write only occurs when all the threads have finished? E.g.

```
with requests_cache.enabled():
    with requests_cache.transaction():
        responses = ThreadPool(100).map(requests.get, urls)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a Django-Rest-Framework application. It works perfectly fine, until requests come in simultaneously. When that happens, the app sometimes starts throwing `database is locked` errors. My first guess was, that the Django-db is overloaded and needed to be replaced with something beefier.

Reproducing the problem by running parallel requests with curl from bash ([see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/456490/execute-curl-requests-in-parallel-in-bash)) gave me fresh logs and traces. I found that requests-cache runs into problems when cleaning out its database. It was configured to cache for 600 seconds, so the first batch-run after the cache was populated would always fail:

```
...
File "/opt/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/core.py" in remove_expired_responses
159.         self.cache.remove_old_entries(datetime.utcnow() - self._cache_expire_after)

File "/opt/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/base.py" in remove_old_entries
117.             self.delete(key)

File "/opt/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/base.py" in delete
83.                 del self.responses[key]

File "/opt/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/storage/dbdict.py" in __delitem__
130.                               self.table_name, (key,))

Exception Type: OperationalError at /app/v1/invitations/
Exception Value: database is locked
```

Looking into possible solutions, I found that `Redis` could be used as backend. I installed Redis and ran it for localhost only. Simply setting the cache-config's `backend` from `sqlite` to 'redis' fixed the problem.

I feel a bit like I am fixing a loose bolt with a hammer, but I'm happy I got it working without breaking anything. I am sure that someone would be able to find a better, more elegant solution, like passing an sqlite-config-param through `requests-cache` or a code-fix.

Answer (score 3):

Since `requests.cache.enabled()` and its [related functions](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html#patching) use monkey-patching, it's unfortunately not thread-safe.

Fortunately, the underlying class that does all the actual caching (`CachedSession`) is thread-safe as of **requests-cache 0.6+** (and improved some more in **0.7+**), so that's probably what you want to use here. There's a full example using `ThreadPoolExecutor` here: https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache/blob/master/examples/threads.py

Like the other answer mentioned, Redis is going to be a better option for concurrent requests, but it's not entirely necessary. SQLite handles concurrency well enough; it supports unlimited concurrent reads, but concurrent writes are internally queued up and run in serial. In a lot of cases this is still fast enough that you won't even notice, but if you're doing really large volumes of concurrent writes, then Redis or [one of the other backends](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/backends.html) is going to be better optimized for that.